# why Java recursion call not release local variable memory

Tags: java, recursion

I have a recursion method like below

```
private void foo(int i){
    byte[] a = new byte[1 * 1024 * 1024];
    System.out.println(i+" "+a.length);
    foo(i+1);
}
```

I find the local variable `a` cannot be released and if I set the maximum heap size 50M (-Xmx50M) it will meet OOM at the 44th call

```
44 1048576
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

but changed it to for loop it does not have this problem

```
private void bar(){
    int index = 1;
    while (true) {
        byte[] a = new byte[1 * 1024 * 1024];
        System.out.println(index+" "+a.length);
        index += 1;
    }
}
```

So why in recursion call it not release the memory of local variable?

Comment: Because it's still in the scope of the all the "active" foo methods on the stack. Why would you expect it to be released?

Comment: @f1sh The question is why the `for` loop doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: @DaveNewton no, the question on the bottom is "So why in recursion call it not release the memory of local variable?"

Comment: @f1sh Hm, yeah. I had it backwards (but in my defense, the OP has it backwards :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In for loop variable a is bound to scope of the for loop so reference to array is released after every iteration and garbage collector can deallocate that memory.

When you do recurssion references of every array is stored on stack so garbage collector can't destroy those arrays since someone(in this case stack) is referencing those arrays. Imagine this situation:

```
private void foo(int i){
    byte[] a = new byte[1 * 1024 * 1024];
    System.out.println(i+" "+a.length);
    foo(i+1);
    a[1] += a[0] + 1;
}
```

This function demonstrates that even after the recursive call array a could still be used.

BONUS: The type of recursion you presented is called tail recursion and there are algorithms that can automatically convert those to loops so in languages like Kotlin you could do this:

```
tailrec fun foo(i: Int): Boolean {
    var a = Array<Byte>(1 * 1024 * 1024, { 0 });
    System.out.println("$i ${a.size}");
    foo(i + 1);
}
```

This would work because Kotlin compiler would turn this into a for or while loop.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the entire question; none of the others explain why the `for` loop works even though it's allocating in every loop.

Comment: No, that's simply a matter of garbage collection. There is only one variable in the loop code. Variables don't get garbage collected - objects do. And arrays are objects.

Answer (score 2):

The release will happen after the method returns, which is after the execution of the first `foo`, but in your case, it calls another `foo`, which also creates a new byte array, and calls a third `foo`, so it accumulates all byte arrays, and Garbage Collector won't try to clear them, until all of them return, or your get OOM.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not deallocate local variables from the stack until the method returns. So even though the local variable will never be used, it is still referenced, and therefore the array cannot be garbage-collected until the method returns.

Also Java does not implement tail call optimisation at all, so there is no early return involved.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion isn't working in this case because java has to have every instance of the method in memory so when you recursively call it it runs out of ram, but when you use a loop it is able to use optimization that it can't use in recursion.

Comment: What "optimization" is that? There's no "optimization" involved AFAIK; can you explain and/or provide a reference?

Comment: The garbage collector.

Comment: Hrm. That's not so much "optimization" as "how the JVM works", no? I mean, there's still a GC running in the recursive version as well, but the value can't be GCed because there's still an active reference.