# when we call recursive function repeatedly the local variables get memory only ones or every time in Java?

Tags: java, variables, recursion, local, factorial

```
int fact(int n){
    int result;
    if(n==1) return 1;
    result=fact(n-1)*n;
    return result;
}
```

So, if i call for fact(3) , for each call **result** variable will get separate memory in stack?

(Sorry if this is a silly question, but I can't seem to grasp this concept.)

Comment: Each call of a function has its own memory in the stack. Otherwise the variables in all the different calls would share the same value.

Comment: This post should answer your question. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044844/why-java-recursion-call-not-release-local-variable-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044844/why-java-recursion-call-not-release-local-variable-memory)

Comment: suppose if 3 calls made then if int(result)  take 4 bytes then 4X3=12 bytes occupied for result variable.   if i write :            int fact(int n)  {  if(n==1 return 1; return n*fact(n-1);} will it be a good choice  ? as there is not extra variable in recursive function.Will it be a great approach in context of space??

Comment: I suggest you check for `n == 0` since `0!` is defined as `1`.  Factorials for `n < 0` are undefined.  And unless using recursion makes the task easier, I would opt for simple iteration.  It's more efficient.  You may even want to consider [memoizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20memoization%20or%20memoisation,the%20same%20inputs%20occur%20again.) previous calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But you don't need to use a variable in this case:

```
int fact(int n){
    if (n==1)
       return 1;
    return fact(n-1)*n;
}
```

Each method invocation will take some space in memory.

> How memory is allocated to different function calls in recursion?
>
> When any function is called from main(), the memory is allocated to it on
> the stack. A recursive function calls itself, the memory for the called
> function is allocated on top of memory allocated to calling function and
> different copy of local variables is created for each function call. When
> the base case is reached, the function returns its value to the function
> by whom it is called and memory is de-allocated and the process continues.

From [recursion in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

A recursive method is the same as any other method. Each time a recursive method is called (either from another method or within itself) it pushes into the separate memory in stack and then pops back when it returns.